# unique word frequency in multiple files

Tags: python, data-mining

I am new to python. I am given a folder with around 2000 text files. I am supposed to output each word and the number of times it occurs (without repetition in a file). For example, the sentence: "i am what i am" must include only one occurrence of "i" in a file.

I am able to do this for a single file, but how do I do it for multiple files?

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def openfile(filename):
    fh = open(filename, "r+")
    str = fh.read()
    fh.close()
    return str

def removegarbage(str):
    # Replace one or more non-word (non-alphanumeric) chars with a space
    str = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str)
    str = str.lower()
    return str

def getwordbins(words):
    cnt = Counter()
    for word in words:
        cnt[word] += 1
    return cnt

def main(filename, topwords):
    txt = openfile(filename)
    txt = removegarbage(txt)
    words = txt.split(' ')
    bins = getwordbins(words)
    for key, value in bins.most_common(topwords):
        print key,value

main('speech.txt', 500)
```

Comment: From your example it seems that the output will always be `1`? Also it seems to me that your code dosn't outputs `2` instead of `1` for your example.

Comment: create a global variable for count "cnt = Counter()" in the script and update it in your respective function.

Comment: Use `words = set(words)` to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of files by using the `glob()` or `iglob()` function in the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob) module. I noted that you weren't using the `Counter` object efficiently. It would be much better to just call its `update()` method and pass it the list of words. Here's a streamlined version of your code that processes all the `*.txt` files found in the specified folder:

```
from collections import Counter
from glob import iglob
import re
import os

def remove_garbage(text):
    """Replace non-word (non-alphanumeric) chars in text with spaces,
       then convert and return a lowercase version of the result.
    """
    text = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', text)
    text = text.lower()
    return text

topwords = 100
folderpath = 'path/to/directory'
counter = Counter()
for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath, '*.txt')):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        counter.update(remove_garbage(file.read()).split())

for word, count in counter.most_common(topwords):
    print('{}: {}'.format(count, word))
```

Answer (score 2):

See `os.listdir()`, it will give you a list of all entries in in a directory.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir

Answer (score 2):

If I got your explanation right,you want to calculate for each word the number of files containing this word. Here is what you could do.

For each file obtain a set of words in this file (that is, words should be unique). Then, for each word count the number of sets it can be found in.

Here is what I suggest:

1. Loop over all the files in the target directory. You can use [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.listdir) for this purpose.
2. Make a set of words found in this file:

   ```
   with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
       txt = removegarbage(f.read())
       words = set(txt.split())
   ```
3. Now when you have a set of words in every file, you can finally use `Counter` with those sets. It's best to use its `update` method. Here is a little demo:

   ```
   >>> a = set("hello Python world hello".split())
   >>> a
   {'Python', 'world', 'hello'}
   >>> b = set("foobar hello world".split())
   >>> b
   {'foobar', 'hello', 'world'}
   >>> c = Counter()
   >>> c.update(a)
   >>> c.update(b)
   >>> c
   Counter({'world': 2, 'hello': 2, 'Python': 1, 'foobar': 1})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

So you might do something a bit like:

```
#!python
from __future__ import print_function
# Your code here
# ...
#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    top=500

    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print ("Must supply a list of files to operate on", file=sys.stderr)
        ## For Python versions older than 2.7 use print >> sys.stderr, "..."
        sys.exit(1)

    for each in sys.argv[1:]:
        main(each, top)
```

Note that I'm showing a simple way to wrap your existing function such that you can call your program with any number of file name arguments.  If you wanted you could also just take a single argument pointing to the directory (from which you want to process all files:

```
#!python
from __future__ import print_function
# Your code here
# ...
# 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    top = 500

    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        ## Require exactly one argument: sys.argv[0] is our own executable filename
        ## (Similarly to how class methods are called with "self" as their first
        ## argument, but on the OS layer)
        print ("Must supply directory name full of files to be processed", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
    for each in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
        main(each, top)
```

There are many other ways you can choose to handle your arguments, hard code default arguments and so on.  I'll leave it to your imagination how to change "top" from being a hard-coded value into a command line argument.  For extra credit make it a command line switch with a default, using the option/arg parsing modules ([argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) or [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)).

Note that this `if __name__ == ....` business is a Python convention which promotes good programming practices by encouraging you to separate your functionality from your actions.  Thus all your functionality can be defined above the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line and all the actions performs by your script (using that functionality) can be called after it.  This allows your file to be used as a module by other programs while still allowing it to have its own utility as a program in its own right.  (This is a feature which is almost unique to Python, though Ruby implements a similar set of semantics which slightly different syntax).

The `__future__` stuff allows you to write a program using Python 2.7 which uses `print` semantics which are compatible with those of Python 3.x.  This is useful for eventually making any transition to Python 3 and also for discussions of the language so we can phase out the old "print" as a statement and promote the use of "print()" the function.  Don't worry if you don't care about the details.  Just realize that the differences are pervasive must mostly minor.  The vast majority of examples you'll see use the old print semantics and you'll want to use newer, slightly incompatible semantics going forward.

(Note: in my initial posting I had the `from __future__ import` in the `__main__` section.  In particular that wouldn't work (and in general Python `__future__` imports should occur before any other code).  [I was basically trying to get the idea across and didn't want to get bogged down in differences between Python2.x and Python3 print semantics.

Comment: `from __future__ import` inside `if`. Wow!

Comment: Ummm, yeah!  About that.  It I've moved that up where it should be.